# Rails & Heroku: application.js loading, but no JQuery events firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app which runs fine locally but none of the jQuery functions are working in production. I've spent way too long on this and am losing hairs by the minute.

My settings:

1. `config.serve_static_files = true` in production.rb
2. ran heroku run rake assets:precompile after pushing
3. rails_12 factor gem is installed in production
4. Jquery cdn is loaded before bootstrap cdn
5. Turbo links uninstalled

Here's my application.html.erb:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

relevant gems:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'jquery-rails'


group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

sample_js_file.js:

```
function initialize() {
console.log('initialized')  <----- GETS CALLED
  $('.avatar').on('click', function(){
      console.log('clicked')  <------- DOES NOT GET CALLED
});

}

$(document).ready(initialize);
$(document).on('page:load', initialize);
```

No errors in the console. Any ideas?

I've tried running rake assets:precompile before pushing but I feel like that's not the path I should be going down (have since cleared the public/assets directory).

Comment: You are loading jQuery twice.

Comment: via //= require jquery  and the google CDN?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where it's being loaded twice.

Comment: try to remove <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @JacksonCunningham, if the application really works flawless locally, maybe a "rake assets:clean", "rake assets:precompile" followed by a server restart helps (on the heroku side). Also, these seem related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758585/jquery-working-in-development-not-production-on-heroku-cedar?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565160/rails-jquery-works-in-localhost-but-not-in-production-on-heroku?rq=1